# How to rearrange these two sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to find an elegant method to rearrange these two sublists:

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = {RandomInteger[10, {4, 2}], RandomInteger[{10, 30}, {4, 2}]}
```

> {{{1,4},{0,7},{0,0},{8,6}},{{11,20},{11,11},{25,17},{27,16}}}

Make these two sublists’ elements have shortest distance from inside to outside. This is my current method:

```
MapAt[Reverse, 
 Transpose[
  Reap[Nest[
     MapThread[
       DeleteCases, {#, 
        Sow[First[
          MinimalBy[Transpose[{First /@ Nearest @@ #, Last[#]}], 
           N[EuclideanDistance @@ #] &]]]}] &, list, 
     Length[First[list]]]][[2, 1]]], {1}]
```

> {{{0,0},{1,4},{0,7},{8,6}},{{11,11},{11,20},{25,17},{27,16}}}

[image]

Show it in graphic:

```
ListPlot[Map[Labeled[#, ToString[#]] &, #] & /@ rearrangPoint, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[.03]]~Show~
 ListLinePlot[
  Reap[Nest[
     MapThread[
       DeleteCases, {#, 
        Sow[First[
          MinimalBy[Transpose[{First /@ Nearest @@ #, Last[#]}], 
           N[EuclideanDistance @@ #] &]]]}] &, list, 
     Length[First[list]]]][[2, 1]], PlotStyle -> ColorData[3], 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

But I have to say this method is too ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Borrowing WReach's idea of using `DeleteDuplicates`:

```
Module[{L = Tuples[list]},
  L = L[[Ordering[EuclideanDistance @@@ L, All, Less]]];
  L = DeleteDuplicates[L, Or @@ MapThread[Equal, {##}] &];
  {Reverse[L[[All, 1]]], L[[All, 2]]}]
```

---

Edit by yode:

```
Transpose[DeleteDuplicates[SortBy[Tuples[list], N[EuclideanDistance @@ #] &], 
   ContainsAny]] // {Reverse[#], #2} & @@ # &
```

---

Edit by coolwater

Note that both of the above code fragments are wrong because of repetitions when choosing an unlucky seed:

```
SeedRandom[63112]
list = {RandomInteger[10, {4, 2}], RandomInteger[{10, 30}, {4, 2}]}
```

The following adds the distinguishability needed within `DeleteDuplicates`:

```
Module[{L = Tuples[Range[Length[Last[list]]], 2]},
  L = L[[Ordering[EuclideanDistance @@@ Tuples[list], All, Less]]];
  L = DeleteDuplicates[L, MemberQ[# - #2, 0] &];
  {list[[1, Reverse[L[[All, 1]]]]], list[[2, L[[All, 2]]]]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for edit,I indeed find too much work should refine still,such as when the sulist's length is unsame.like `list = {{{1, 4}, {0, 7}, {0, 0}, {8, 6}}, {{11, 20}, {11, 11}, {27, 
    16}}}`.The result of `{{{0,0},{1,4},{0,7},{8,6}},{{11,11},{11,20},{27,16}}}` is expected.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a shorter, though not necessarily prettier, solution:

```
ReplaceList[list, {{___, l_, ___}, {___, r_, ___}} :> {l, r} -> N@EuclideanDistance[l, r]] //
SortBy[Last] //
DeleteDuplicates[#, #[[1, 1]] == #2[[1, 1]] || #[[1, 2]] == #2[[1, 2]]&] & //
{#[[All, 1, 1]] // Reverse, #[[All, 1, 2]]} &


(* {{{0, 0}, {1, 4}, {0, 7}, {8, 6}}, {{11, 11}, {11, 20}, {25, 17}, {27, 16}}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

***Elegant*** is completely subjective. It could mean ***short*** or possibly ***easy to follow*** or something entirely different.

The solution below is not the shortest but I do find it relatively easy to follow.

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = {RandomInteger[10, {4, 2}], RandomInteger[{10, 30}, {4, 2}]}

(* { {{1, 4},   {0, 7},   {0, 0},   {8, 6}},
     {{11, 20}, {11, 11}, {25, 17}, {27,16}} } *)
```

### Step 1 - newList

A function is defined that will take as input the form of your list:

```
  {set1,                                 set2}
                                    ⇓
{{{w1, x1}, {w2, x2}, ..., {wn, xn}}, {{y1, z1}, {y2, z2}, ..., {yn, zn}}}
```

It will find the pair `{{wi,xi}, {yj,zj}}` that represents the minimum distance, `Sow` it and return the complete list with `{wi,zi}` removed from `set1` and `{yj,zj}` removed from `set2`.

```
newList[list_] := Module[
  {
   tuplesList = Tuples[list],
   distanceList,
   minimum,
   position,
   pair
   },
  distanceList = N@EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ tuplesList;
  minimum = N@Min[distanceList];
  position = Position[distanceList, minimum];
  pair = Flatten[Extract[tuplesList, position], 1];
  Sow[pair];
  {DeleteCases[list[[1]], pair[[1]]], 
   DeleteCases[list[[2]], pair[[2]]]}
  ]
```

Test it on the complete list

```
newList[list]

(* {{{1, 4}, {0, 7}, {0, 0}}, {{11, 20}, {25, 17}, {27, 16}}} *)
```

### Step 2 - sortedNestedList

Using `newList` we produce a sorted list using `Nest`, `Sow` and `Reap`.

```
sortedNestedList = Reap[Nest[newList, list, Length@list[[1]]]][[2, 1]]

(* { {{8, 6}, {11, 11}}, {{0, 7}, {11, 20}},
     {{1, 4}, {25, 17}}, {{0, 0}, {27, 16}}} *)
```

### Step 3 - Extract the final answer

The final list is extracted from `sortedNestedList` by reversing the first column (new `set1`) and simply copying the second column (new `set2`).

```
{Reverse@sortedNestedList[[All, 1]], sortedNestedList[[All, 2]]}

(* { {{0, 0},   {1, 4},   {0, 7},   {8, 6}},
     {{11, 11}, {11, 20}, {25, 17}, {27, 16}}} *)
```

### Putting it all together

The function `sortedList` encapsulates the previous three steps

```
sortedList[list_] := Module[
  {
   sortedNestedList = 
    Reap[Nest[newList, list, Length@list[[1]]]][[2, 1]]
   },
  {Reverse@sortedNestedList[[All, 1]], sortedNestedList[[All, 2]]}
  ]
```

Testing it on the original list

```
sortedList[list]

(* { {{0, 0},   {1, 4},   {0, 7},   {8, 6}},
     {{11, 11}, {11, 20}, {25, 17}, {27, 16}}} *)
```